# Constructor c++ Object obj = Object("string", 22); creating a temporary Object?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, assignment-operator

I asked in the chat area of stackoverflow the following question.

If you create your object like this does it create a temporary and then call the assignment operator to assign the temp to the obj object?

```
Object obj = Object( "Chris", 27 );
```

I was told that it just calls the constructor.

However when I run the code, the console prints out that the dtor was called on the very next line, which means a temporary was constructed and that must mean the assignment operator is called too right?

So if that is true then does that mean that writing your constructors like this

```
Object obj( "Chris", 22 );
```

actually run much faster since you are avoiding a temporary ctor and dtor, and assignment operator.  When I run the code like above no dtor string is printed to the console until the end of the function.  So it seems like no temporary was created and my code will run more efficiently.

```
class Object
{
public:
Object()
     {
     mSize = 0;
     }
Object( string & name, int size )
     :
     mName(name),
     mSize(size)
     {
     }

~Object()
     {
     cout << "Object Dtor called" << endl;
     }
string mName;
int mSize;
};
```

Comment: The copy can be elided by the compiler, but it depends on the compiler and the options used.  What are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop

Comment: Are you building debug or release?

Comment: I am more interested in what the standard says than compiler settings.

Comment: I went ahead and tried it in both release and debug and both show a temporary.

Comment: @EddieV223 can you show your main function about how do you call it?

Comment: If `Object` has a move constructor, then you can be sure that line will not call a copy constructor.

Comment: By the way, something like `Object o = 5;` is called copy initialization, and calls the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case the compiler is instructed in creating the object once. In the first case you are asking to create a temporary which is then copied to a new object. In this case the compiler can *decide* to replace the creation-copy-destruction to the more efficient creation of a single object. So you must be prepared to this possibility but you cannot rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` in a declaration is not an assignment. No assignment operator is invoked. A C++ textbook is a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply update your class to output exactly what it is doing, then you would know, eg:

```
class Object
{
public:
Object()
     :
     mSize(0)
     {
     cout << "Object default Ctor called" << endl;
     }

Object(const Object & src )
     :
     mName(src.mName),
     mSize(src.mSize)
     {
     cout << "Object copy Ctor called" << endl;
     }

Object( string & name, int size )
     :
     mName(name),
     mSize(size)
     {
     cout << "Object name Ctor called" << endl;
     }

~Object()
     {
     cout << "Object Dtor called" << endl;
     }

Object& operator=(const Object &rhs)
    {
    cout << "Object Assigment Op called" << endl;
    mName = rhs.mName;
    mSize = rhs.mSize;
    }

string mName;
int mSize;
};
```